# i want to print the ajax hint value in textbox

Tags: ajax

i want to print the value in textbox i tried to make text box `id="txtHint"`
but it doesn't work 
how can i do that ?

```
<script>
function showHint(str) {
    if (str.length == 0) { 
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "gethint.php?q=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute your code in FireFox or Chrome (firebug) and check if you are getting response for the ajax call.

Comment: then you need to verify your gethint.php?q= call, also check it from the php side. Your txtHint will be added with appropriate value only if you have  value in the response.

Comment: i made gethint.php and it works as a hint on spain only